# Passer à travers (quelque chose)

Tags: expressions, complément-cod

> Les voix effleurent mon esprit et **passent à travers**.

Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte telle quelle ou il faut absolument ajouter *à travers mon esprit* ? Tous les exemples que j'ai vus sur Internet ont un COD après *passer à travers*...

Comment: On dit « passer **au** travers **de** quelque chose » et « passer **à** travers quelque chose », mais jamais « passer à travers de quelque chose ».

Comment: @LPH Oui, merci. Je confonds parfois ces expressions. Je vais corriger le titre.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une question de style ; « mon » esprit peut être placé après « au travers » en tant que  complément prépositionnel et « à travers » est alors une locution prépositionnelle, mais ce n'est pas habituel ; normalement, sans répéter « mon esprit », on comprend que « passent à travers » signifie « passent à travers mon esprit », et « à travers » est un [pro-adverbe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro-adverbe). On peut aussi utiliser le pronom « lui ».

- Les voix effleurent mon esprit et passent à travers lui.

Il peut exister une ambiguité due à l'expression idiomatique familière « [passer à travers](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passer) » ; si on veut alors préserver « passer à travers » avec le sens  voulu, il suffit d'utiliser le pronom « lui ».

Comment: Merci pour le lien, j'y ai trouvé une phrase avec _passer à travers_ sans COD. _Quels cheveux sans couleur, à force d'être blonds! On dirait que le jour **passe à travers**_ (Stendhal, Rouge et Noir, 1830, p.282)

Comment: "On dirait que le jour passe à travers" [implique l'antécédent:  les cheveux].

Comment: @Lambie D'où les termes  « **pro**nom »,  « **pro**forme » et « **pro**-adverbe ».

Comment: Faut pas oublier: proverbe :)

Comment: @Lambie Vous pouvez  en profiter… pas moi…

Comment: Lá, tu me perds.

Answer (score 1):

Aucun problème grammatical mais on pourrait déceler un problème de logique.

Au sens propre au moins, on peut difficilement passer à travers de quelque chose qu'on a seulement effleuré.

L'expression *effleurer mon esprit* est bien sûr au sens figuré mais elle s'applique plutôt à une idée ou une pensée qu'une voix, et elle inclut déjà l'idée de départ rapide, d'oubli, si c'est ce que *à travers* signifie.

Comment: _on peut difficilement passer à travers de quelque chose qu'on a seulement effleuré_ Oui, j'y ai pensé. Pas grave. :) Disons, les voix atteignent mon esprit, je n'y prête aucune attention et elles passent à travers sans que je les distingue. // Mais tu écris aussi _à travers **de** quelque chose_, Antidote dit que c'est vieilli, mais j'aime bien cette expression.

Comment: *Passer à travers **de** quelque chose* est redevenu courant. Le prescriptivisme qui le condamne me semble exagéré. On l'entend et le lit souvent.

Comment: *L’Olympique de Marseille est encore passé **à travers de son match** de championnat, dimanche lors de la réception de Monaco.* [Beinsports-2022](https://www.beinsports.com/france/ligue-1/video/om-sampaoli-ne-panique-pas/1843435)

Comment: Tant mieux ! Merci. J'aime bien _à travers de_. :)